# Javascript: get video duration

Tags: javascript, html, video

I want to get the duration of video by javascript and this code doesn't work

```
<video id="myVideo">
     <source src="">
</video>
<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
alert(vid.duration);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the file's metadata to load:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
     console.log(vid.duration);
});
```